# "Stack Exchange" is used improperly on reputation league pages

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues, legal, trademark

The [Reputation Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow) sidebar explains:

> These friendly reputation leagues are an informal way of tracking your reputation within the community on a particular Stack Exchange.

which does not conform to [trademark use guidelines](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance):

> The phrase "Stack Exchange" is generally used as an adjective, not a noun. One would say "Propose a Stack Exchange site on Area 51" (correct), not "Propose a Stack Exchange on Area 51" (wrong).

Comment: I'm just waiting for someone to come along and hit you with a giant noun.

Answer (score 5):

This is quite weird because before that, they did use "Stack Exchange" as an adjective:

> When your fellow users vote up your questions and answers on a Stack Exchange site, you generate reputation. Reputation is a rough measure of:

Since, they probably mean "Stack Exchange site", the easiest fix is to insert the word "site" at the end of the sentence:

> These friendly reputation leagues are an informal way of tracking your reputation within the community on a particular Stack Exchange site.